# open word document inside a windows 8 metro application

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Now i'm open a word document in windows 8 Metro apps. I don't know if is it possible.  but i have open the word document inside a windows 8 Metro apps. ex: open the word document in gmail using iPad.

here is my code,

```
string file = @"Assets\sample.docx";

var getFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(file);
        if (getFile != null)
        {
             var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(getFile);
        }
```

this is open for a word file. but i have open inside a windows 8 metro application.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to open a Word file from a Windows 8 Metro/Windows Store app just using [file activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452684.aspx).  Since a .docx or .doc file is already associated with the Word program, it should launch Word as a separate process and open the file within Word, from your app.

However, it doesn't run Word inside of your app.  That is not possible.

Comment: is there any best way to open word document in windows 8 metro apps except Launchers